# Getting the max possible display rate of connected monitors

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to get programmatically the maximum display rate that Windows allows (i.e, Display settings > Advanced display settings > Refresh rate > max value). Chances are, there's no such query and I instead need to obtain all the possible options. How do I do that ?

I've already obtained the monitor names and current refresh rates using the [CCD API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/ccd-apis), by obtaining `DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO`s and by using `DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo`. But I can't seem to find a way to obtain the refresh rate options associated to a monitor. A CCD API based solution would be perfect, but an alternative is fine - it just means I'll have to reconcile the information obtained via the CCD API with that obtained from that other API, somehow.

Also, I'm trying to do this in the context of a plain Windows executable, that doesn't use a specific graphics backend library (ex DX12) or game-making framework.

Thanks !

Comment: You can use `EnumDisplaySettingsW` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaysettingsw and group all the DEVMODE (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea#syntax) returned by the `dmDisplayFrequency` field. Use `DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_DEVICE_NAME` 's `viewGdiDeviceName` field value as the first parameter of `EnumDisplaySettingsW`.

Comment: @SimonMourier Hey thanks, I got it working. Feel free to post it as an answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the CCD API, you can use [DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-displayconfiggetdeviceinfo) to get the GDI device name using [DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_TYPE::DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_SOURCE_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ne-wingdi-displayconfig_device_info_type) , usually something like `\\.\DISPLAY1`, `\\.\DISPLAY2`, etc.

Once you have that device name, you can use the [EnumDisplaySettingsW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaysettingsw)  to enumerate all [DEVMODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea) for this device, this will give you all possible combination of modes (resolution, frequency, etc.) that the device supports (that can easily return hundreds of modes).

Once you have that you just need to group them by DEVMODE's `dmDisplayFrequency` field (and sort it).